# View website visit stats Heroku / Streamlit

Tags: heroku, streamlit

Is there a way to track how many visits I have to my website? If yes, is there a way to add a counter to a streamlit application?

Comment: never thoughtabout it but if you run an express server, so to say, you can define a global variable incremented with every call to a route

Comment: If relying on Google Analytics is not a problem just add the tracking bit right after your `<head>` block.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Google Analytics:

```py
anlytcs_code = """<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>"""

# Fetch the path of the index.html file
path_ind = os.path.dirname(st.__file__)+'/static/index.html'

# Open the file
with open(path_ind, 'r') as index_file:
    data=index_file.read()

    # Check whether there is GA script
    if len(re.findall('UA-', data))==0:

        # Insert Script for Google Analytics
        with open(path_ind, 'w') as index_file_f:

            # The Google Analytics script should be pasted in the header of the HTML file
            newdata=re.sub('<head>','<head>'+anlytcs_code,data)

            index_file_f.write(newdata)
```

While using the above code, replace the value of the id with the one generated for your project on Google Analytics.

[Reference](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-add-google-analytics-or-js-code-in-a-streamlit-app/1610/18)

Answer (score 0):

https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-google-analytics-tracking-code-to-dash-app/17297/5

i found a better answer here like following:

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.index_string = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-131327483-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-131327483-1');
        </script>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
    </head>
    <body>
        {%app_entry%}
        <footer>
            {%config%}
            {%scripts%}
            {%renderer%}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>"""
```